# doubt in the chapter of multinomial theorem

Tags: binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem, multinomial-coefficients, multinomial-theorem

the question stated to find the sum of all coefficients divisible by 37 in the expansion of $ (2x+y+z)^{37} $

I proceeded by writing out

$ (2x+y+z)^{37} $ = $ \sum_{0  \le  p,q,r \le 37} $ (${ (37!)   2^p \over   (p! (q!) (r!)}$ ) $ x^p y^q z^ r $ where p + q + r = 37.

but got stuck at this point

Comment: Well, can you get the sum of *all* the coefficients?  If so, you might then be able to get the sum of all the coefficients prime to $37$ and then subtract.

Comment: Or directly: $0\le p,q,37-p-q<37\iff[(p=0\land1\le q\le 36)\lor(p\ge1\land0\le q\le36)].$